# JavaScript, objetos dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Necesito ayuda con este ejercicio, tengo que devolver el objeto, que esta dentro de un `array`, cuya propiedad `nombre` coincida con el string `nombre`.

Este código me salta el error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nombre')"**

```javascript
function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) {
  // La funcion llamada 'buscarAmigo' recibe como argumento un array llamado 'amigos' que contiene
  // en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que tiene como propiedades 'nombre' y 'edad'. También
  // recibe un string llamado 'nombre'.
  // Debe devolver el objeto cuya propiedad 'nombre' coincida con el string 'nombre' recibido por argumento.
  // Ej:
  //  var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
  //  buscarAmigo(amigos, 'toni') debe devolver { nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 };

  // Tu código aca:
  amigos.forEach(object => {
    if (object.nombre === nombre) {
      return amigos
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías mejorar la formulación de la pregunta, hay partes repetidas y el código no parece completo.

Según lo que se puede apreciar, para empezar no estás devolviendo en el `return` el amigo en sí, sino el array completo.

Por otro lado, si decides usar el `foreach` será mejor que utilices una variable externa para almacenar el resultado del iterador, ya que sino estarías haciendo algo así como varios return.

El código quedaría así:

```js
var lista_amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) {
    var amigo_encontrado;
    amigos.forEach(amigo => { 
        if (amigo.nombre === nombre) {
            amigo_encontrado = amigo;
         }
    } ); 
    
    if (amigo_encontrado) { return amigo_encontrado } else { return  "Parece que no hay ningún amigo con ese nombre" };
}

console.log(buscarAmigo(lista_amigos, "toni"));
```

Otra solución podría ser usando la función `Array.some`  ([Docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

Esta respuesta es la ideal ya que no se recorre todo el array en caso de no ser necesario, lo cual hace que el código sea más preciso.

```js
var lista_amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) {
    var amigo_encontrado;
    amigos.some(function(amigo) {
        if ( nombre === amigo.nombre) {
            amigo_encontrado = amigo;
        }
    });
    if (amigo_encontrado) { return amigo_encontrado } else { return  "Parece que no hay ningún amigo con ese nombre" };
    
}

console.log(buscarAmigo(lista_amigos, "toni"));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! si funcionó.

Comment: Te consulto... ¿Se podría realizar con un bucle for?

Comment: Así es, sería definir un for donde ahora está el forEach de esta manera: 

for (var i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) { 
    //El método
}